# Chain flowable to completable with action

Tags: android, sql, rx-android, android-room

I have Android Room's SQL query, that return flowable:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE lang = 'ru' AND id_exercice = :id")
Flowable<Exercices> getExercicesById(int id);
```

In my repository, I need get emitted element, than change his boolean value, then call new method, that must returns completable.
That's what I try:

```
@Override
public Completable setExerciseUsed(int id) {
    return mDatabase.exerciseDao().getExercicesById(id)
            .doOnNext(exercise -> exercise.setIs_used(1))
            .flatMapCompletable(exercise ->
                    Completable.fromAction(() -> mFitnessDatabase.exerciseDao().addExercise(exercise)));
}
```

Also i tried:

```
Exercices e = mDatabase.exerciseDao().getExercicesById(id).blockingFirst();
    e.setIs_used(0);
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> mDatabase.exerciseDao().addExercise(e));
```

But t not works properly. It seems like flowable emits many elements, and it going to stuck in cycle, after subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Since your DAO returns Flowable, it will emit fresh data each time table is modified.
So after calling `mFitnessDatabase.exerciseDao().addExercise(exercise)`,
`getExercicesById` will emit new data, thus the chain will execute forever.
If you want Room not to emit data - just change Flowable to Single.
Since you expect the one value to e returned, it's a good idea to limit the result to one item:  `"SELECT * FROM exercices WHERE lang = 'ru' AND id_exercice = :id LIMIT 1"`.

But actually, in your case, if you want to change a parameter of an item, it's much more efficient to do this within one query.
It may look like:

```
@Query("UPDATE exercices SET is_used = 1  WHERE lang = 'ru' AND id_exercice = :id")
fun setIsUsed(id: Int)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about flowables or how to unsubscribe from one source with those, but have you thought about using LiveData? You can simply add a source to a LiveData object, then remove the connection to the source, change the object and execute your method without going into loop.

Another idea would it be that you retrieve your object, keep the connection and updating the value outside of that. Because you are keeping the database connection with LiveData, the observer would execute the onChanged again (because the source = database has been changed). You only would need to make sure that this method returns for example null (via setValue) for the time being until the database uploaded the new object value.

If you want to stay with flowables, maybe you should consider adding a condition which will prevent the app from re-applying the integer to the object (and sending it to the database). Does that makes sense to you?